# How to group an array by Month and Year React Native

Tags: react-native

i have an json response like this :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 2984,
            "amount": 5000000,
            "account": "money",
            "trade_no": "2121683414670617655",
            "type": 0,
            "for_id": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-02-16 20:50:14",
            "payment_method": 0,
            "status": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2999,
            "amount": -450000,
            "account": "money",
            "trade_no": "212173166272246C118",
            "type": 5,
            "for_id": "2021021760479",
            "created_at": "2021-01-17 10:14:22",
            "payment_method": "0",
            "status": 1
        },
        
    ],
    "code": 200,
    "description": "OK"
}
```

and then i want grouping the api by month and year look like this :

[image]

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy method from lodash.

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(result, function(item) {
    return item.created_at.substring(0,7);
});
```

This will give you data in below format:

```
{
    "2021-02": [
        {
            "id": 2984,
            "amount": 5000000,
            "account": "money",
            "trade_no": "2121683414670617655",
            "type": 0,
            "for_id": 0,
            "created_at": "2021-02-16 20:50:14",
            "payment_method": 0,
            "status": 1
        }
    ],
    "2021-01": [
        {
            "id": 2999,
            "amount": -450000,
            "account": "money",
            "trade_no": "212173166272246C118",
            "type": 5,
            "for_id": "2021021760479",
            "created_at": "2021-01-17 10:14:22",
            "payment_method": "0",
            "status": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

When rendering the data, you can format your Year-Month key to string using moment like this,

```
moment('2021-01', 'YYYY-MM').format('MMMM YYYY');
```